# SSRS horizontal alignment in a straight line

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm new to SSRS and I'm unable to align the sentence horizontally in a straight line in SSRS using HTML tag.

I've got a very long word and I want it to fit in a line. I tried using can grow in SSRS but it expands the text box in a vertical manner with the word moving to the next line. However, I want the words to fit in a horizontal line and the extra to be visible as long as the text box holds.

Is there any HTML tag/code in SSRS which would help me achieve the same?

Comment: What tags are you trying to use and what result are you trying to get? There may be another way to achieve the outcome you want.

Comment: Hi Chris, I've a very long word and I want it to fit in a line. I tried using can grow in SSRS but it fits the word in a vertical manner in the next line but I want the words to fit in a horizontal line and the extra to be visible as long as the text box holds. Is there any HTML tag/code in SSRS which would help me achieve the same?

Comment: Okay, try the method I've added to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS only supports a very limited set of HTML tags, so HTML is often not that helpful to format your text.

From [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562.aspx), the list of supported tags are:

- Hyperlinks: `<A HREF>`
- Fonts: `<FONT>`
- Header, style and block elements: `<H{n}>`, `<DIV>`, `<SPAN>`, `<P>`, `<HN>`
- Text format: `<B>`, `<I>`, `<U>`, `<S>`
- List handling: `<OL>`, `<UL>`, `<LI>`

So we can achieve the result you are after (that is, show as much of the text as possible in the horizontal confines of the text box) by combining the `<DIV>` HTML element with non-breaking spaces.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Set the cell's `CanGrow` property to `False` so it won't expand vertically
2. Set the cell's Markup Type to be `HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles`
3. Enclose the field's text in `<DIV>` tags and replace the spaces in the text with non-breaking spaces by setting the cell's expression to:

   `="<DIV>" & Replace(Fields!FieldName.Value, " ", "&nbsp") & "</DIV>"`

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! This worked perfectly as I wanted it to.